# Npm start error: events.js:292 throws unhandled exception

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm starting to study React and I'm trying to create a new react app using create-react-app tool. After successful creation, I use npm start and the following message appears:

```
events.js:292  
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT  
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)  
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)  
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)  
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:  
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)  
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)  
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)  
{  
  errno: 'ENOENT',  
  code: 'ENOENT',  
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',  
  path: 'cmd',  
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]  
}  

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR! errno 1  
npm ERR! react-tut@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the react-tut@0.1.0 start script.  
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-09T20_07_11_717Z-debug.log
```

The log file says:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok  
1 verbose cli [  
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',  
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Diego\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',  
1 verbose cli   'start'  
1 verbose cli ]  
2 info using npm@6.14.6  
3 info using node@v12.18.1  
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]  
5 info lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~prestart: react-tut@0.1.0  
6 info lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: react-tut@0.1.0  
7 verbose lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true  
8 verbose lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Programação\Javascript\reactApp\react-tut\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Users\Diego\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs  
9 verbose lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: CWD:  C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Programação\Javascript\reactApp\react-tut  
10 silly lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]  
11 silly lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null  
12 info lifecycle react-tut@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script  
13 verbose stack Error: react-tut@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`  
13 verbose stack Exit status 1  
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)  
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)  
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)  
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)  
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)  
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)  
14 verbose pkgid react-tut@0.1.0  
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Programação\Javascript\reactApp\react-tut  
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363  
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"  "C:\\Users\\Diego\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"  
18 verbose node v12.18.1  
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6  
20 error code ELIFECYCLE  
21 error errno 1  
22 error react-tut@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`  
22 error Exit status 1  
23 error Failed at the react-tut@0.1.0 start script.  
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've already looked other answers but I can't find a solution. Appreciate if you could help me!

Comment: Somehow your react-scripts does not find the cmd Command. What happens if you do Win+R and enter cmd and press enter?

Comment: Opens a new terminal window

Answer (score 2):

Add `C:\Windows\System32` to the global `%PATH%` environment variable: it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Run `npx react-scripts start` It should work